# "DNS lookup failed" Error only for few networks

Tags: web, dns, server, vps

I have been developing a website and hosted that website on Godaddy(VPS Hosting). My website address is http://paisamint.com, for last one week my website was working fine, but suddenly from today morning itself I'm getting "DNS LOOKUP FALILED" error only for my network( Am using Airtel India), If I user other networks like TATA Docomo and Vodafone I can able to see my website perfectly. I don't know what to do. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on your operating system, but did you try [flushdns](https://www.whatsmydns.net/flush-dns.html)?

Comment: I have done that too. But still the error is there (DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN and  ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED). Please check the screenshot also http://prntscr.com/8r5jgc

Comment: Did you try to add a new dns server? Since it seems like your providers DNS server doesn't like your page.